# Conditional comments in Ractive mustache template

Tags: html, ms-office, ractivejs

Conditional comments do not work in Ractive, I tried these so far:

1)
Template:

```
<li class="header-link">
  <!--[if !IE]><a href="{{url}}">BROWSE</a><![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE]><a href="{{url}}">BROWSE</a><![endif]-->
</li>
```

Output:

```
<li class="header-link"> </li>
```

---

2)
Template:

```
<li class="header-link">
  {{{ifnotie}}}<a href="{{url}}">BROWSE</a>{{{ifend}}}
  {{{ifie}}}<a href="{{url}}">BROWSE</a>{{{ifend}}}
</li> 


data: { 
      ifie: '<!--[if IE]>',
    ifnotie: '<!--[if !IE]>', 
    ifend: '<![endif]-->',
    url: 'www.google.com'
    }
```

Output:

```
<li class="header-link">
<!--[if !IE]>--><a href="www.google.com">BROWSE</a><!--[endif]----> 
<!--[if IE]>--><a href="www.google.com">BROWSE</a><!--[endif]---->
</li>
```

When I put the comments in the data, Ractive modifies the comments so they don't work anymore.

```
<!--[if IE]> ====> <!--[if !IE]>-->
```

---

I was wondering if there is any work around to this

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in the solution, I end up replacing {{{ifnotie}}}{{{ifend}}}
with regex to conditions ( {{ifnotie}}{{/ifnotie}} ) and feeding environment specific data to the Ractive based on the suggestion in Github.

https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/3103